# My uploaded files are not saved to the Database

Tags: python, django

my model

```
class FactuurBestanden(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to='profile_pics')
```

my form

```
class FactuurBestandenForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = FactuurBestanden
        fields = '__all__'
```

my view

```
def createFacturenAdmin(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = FactuurBestandenForm(request.POST, request.FIlES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                print("form not valid")
            return redirect("facturatie_admin")
        form = FactuurBestandenForm()
        return render(request, 'users/admin_facturatie.html', {'form':form})
```

and my template

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <button style="margin-left: 40px" class="Button1" type="submit">Click here</button>

</form>
```

The uploaded files are not saved to the DB ? what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your html tag  :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You can read this for further info:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html